# How to do the setup for deploying Full-stack (Monggose, Express, Reactjs, Nodejs) website on Netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, netlify

I have a website that deployed to Herokuapp. But unfortunately, the herokuapp had a problem to upload an image to a local folder so I tried to deploy my website to another site that is Netlify.

Here comes the problem. I only knew the build setup just for deploying to herokuapp, so this is my setup :

My Folder structure :

```
/client <-- "this is my create-react-app folder"
/config
/models
/routes
/validation
package.json
server.js <-- "my server"
```

package.json

```
/* some settings */
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
/* some settings */
```

I don't know how to run the "heroku-postbuild" setting on Netlify to make it work. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you realize you will not be able to run Mongoose and Express on Netlify for a full stack configuration? Netlify uses nodejs during the build process of your client side application, then deploys those assets up to its CDN.You will be hosting your server side database on a different hosting platform or cloud service.

Comment: hmm, is that so. thank you then!

Comment: You can use Heroku-Mlab db, which is free for 500MB.